# Vue.js two-way data binding with deep properties: watcher in child component double triggers and reverts on first click

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm experiencing an unusual issue in a Vue.js application involving two-way data binding on a object.

In my setup, a parent component passes a object as a prop to a child component. The child component updates a property of this object on a click event. The watcher updates the value correctly, then the parent function (updateSelectedOptions) is called, which is the expected behavior. However, the child component's watcher runs again and reverts the value to its original state. This happens only on the first click.

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <ShopProductOptions
    
    :selected-options="selectedOptions"
    @update:selectedOptions="updateSelectedOptions"
  />
</template>

<script setup>

const selectedOptions = ref({});

const updateSelectedOptions = (newSelections) => {
  console.log('Updating selected options in parent:', newSelections);
  selectedOptions.value = newSelections;
};

</script>
```

Child Component (ShopProductOptions):

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
    <span
      class="option-item"
      @click="setSelectedOption(option.name, value)"
    >
      {{option.name}}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
  options: Array,
  selectedOptions: Object
});

const localSelectedOptions = ref({ ...props.selectedOptions });
const emit = defineEmits(['update:selectedOptions']);

const setSelectedOption = (optionName, value) => {
  localSelectedOptions.value[optionName] = value;
  emit('update:selectedOptions', localSelectedOptions.value);
};

watch(localSelectedOptions, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  console.log('Watcher triggered in child:', newVal, oldVal);
}, { deep: true });
</script>
```

Issue:

Upon the first click on an option, the `updateSelectedOptions` method in the parent component is called, updating `selectedOptions`. Immediately after, the watcher in the child component is triggered again, reverting back to the previous value.

This issue only happens on the first click; subsequent clicks update the value as expected without any reversion.

I'm puzzled as to why this sequence of events and the resulting reversion occurs only on the first interaction. Is this related to the initial synchronization of the nested object between the parent and child, or is there another aspect of Vue's reactivity system at play here? Any insights or solutions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use destructure to initial the `localSelectedOptions` in your child component instead of reference.

use a `ComputedRef` instead of `Ref` could manage the value which shared in parent-child-components clearly, also, watch the value from parent directly instead of the copy in the child component

in your child component

```
<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
  options: Array,
  selectedOptions: Object
});

const emit = defineEmits(['update:selectedOptions']);

// before
const localSelectedOptions = ref({ ...props.selectedOptions });

const setSelectedOption = (optionName, value) => {
  localSelectedOptions.value[optionName] = value;
  emit('update:selectedOptions', localSelectedOptions.value);
};


// after
const localSelectedOptions = computed({
    get () {
        return props.selectedOptions;
    },
    set (value) {
        emit('update:selectedOptions', value);
    }
});

const setSelectedOption = (optionName, value) => {
    localSelectedOptions.value[optionName] = value;
};


// before
watch(localSelectedOptions, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  console.log('Watcher triggered in child:', newVal, oldVal);
}, { deep: true });

// after
watch(() => props.selectedOptions, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  console.log('Watcher triggered in child:', newVal, oldVal);
}, { deep: true });

</script>
```